# How to write a piecewise function to take a list of {value,point} as its parameter?

Tags: piecewise

I want to apply Piecewise function to a list of range and values, for example, to make

```
f[{{v1,r2},{v2,r2},{v3,r3},{v4,r4},...,{vn,\[Infinity]}}]
```

generate:

```
Piecewise[{{v1, x < r1}}, 
 Piecewise[{{v2, x < r2}}, 
  Piecewise[{{v3, x < r3}}, 
   Piecewise[{{v4, x < r4}}, ...
    Piecewise[{{v(n-1), x < r(n-1)}}, vn]]]]]
```

How should I write function f?

I've tried this but failed:

```
pw[{v_, r_}, k_] = Piecewise[{{v, k < r}}]
FoldList[pw, x, {{v1, r1}, {v2, r2}, {v3, r3}}] // Last
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The output contains `pw[x, {v1, r1}]`, now take a look at your definition of `pw`.

Comment: Are you certain you do not want `Piecewise@MapAt[x < # &, {All, -1}]@{{v1, r1}, {v2, r2}, {v3, r3}}`?

Comment: Thanks @Edmund . This works. So when specifying `x<r2`, it does not need to tell piecewise `r1 <= x < r2`, right? That is so simple. Great!

Comment: @cmal Correct. No need for the extra specification because the value of the first test that is successful is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to nest [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html).

```
Piecewise@MapAt[x < # &, {All, -1}]@{{v1, r1}, {v2, r2}, {v3, r3}}
```

> ```
> Piecewise[{{v1, x < r1}, {v2, x < r2}, {v3, x < r3}}, 0]
> ```

Hope this helps.